# Какой процесс использует максимально диск

Tags: bash

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно определить какой процесс использует максимально диск?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте iotop:

```bash
sudo iotop
```

Установить в debian-подобных системах можно следующей командой:

```bash
sudo apt install iotop
```